# How to store connectionstring in appsetting.json when dockerize .net core application

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core

I'm learning Docker and trying to run a container of a .NET core app which uses Redis in another container.
The thing is the .NET core app get the connection string of Redis from appsetting.json file. But how do i know the ip of the Redis container when using docker or docker compose and write it down in appsettings.json? The only thing i know is Redis running on port 6379. Is there a way to configure it automatically?

Comment: You have to know the name of the container if they are on the same stack they can just talk to eachother using the container name.  otherwise you need to know the ip or domain name where the redis is running

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro can you be more specific? if they are on the same network and the name of redis container is "redis", then using "redis:6379" in my appsettings.json will be automatically resolved?

Comment: if they are on the same docker network you can just use the container name.  for example i had an api exposed on a container called appApi and another container consumes it i would call it like http://appApi/

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a network and specify the dependency on Redis in the "depends_on" field.

Example for docker-compose:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  myapi:
    image: myapi
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    networks:
      - myapi-network
    depends_on:
      - "redismyapi"

  redismyapi:
    image: redis:alpine
    ports:
      - "16379:6379"
    networks:
      - myapi-network

networks: 
    myapi-network:
        driver: bridge
```

Then, configure Redis in your project's startup.

```
// Redis config
builder.Services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options =>
{
   options.Configuration = 
   builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionRedis");
   options.InstanceName = "RedisCache";
});
```

Finally, add the "ConnectionString" to the "appsettings.json" file.

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "ConnectionRedis": "redismyapi"
}
```

Note: The ConnectionString here is the name of the redis instance in docker-compose.